# How to apply a random forest model to a new dataset without a response variable in R?

Tags: predictive-models, random-forest

I am trying to predict the species abundance on a new data set using my random forest model. The RF regression model was built using a training dataset 70% and validated using 30% of the initial data set aside at the beginning. The model worked great and I got the results I wanted. Now I want to use that model to calculate the predictions of a species abundance on a new data set which does not contain the response variable, is this possible?

My current RF model is:

```r
RF <- randomForest(
    x = Manatee[, c("Season", "Month", "Seagrass", "Wwrefuge", "Bathymetry", "Salinity", "Wtemp")],
    y=Manatee$Count,
    ntree = 3000,
    mtry = 3,
    importance = T,
    keep.forest = T
)
```

- where the 'Count' of manatees is the response variable,
- the season, month, seagrass, wwrefuge, bathymetry, salinity, and wtemp are the predictor variables

The new dataset I have contains the same predictor variables but does not have a Count value associated with it. I have tried running the predict function in randomforest but keep getting the error "*Type of predictors in new data do not match the training data.*"

```r
RF.pred <- predict(
    RF,
    newdata = newManateedata[, c("Season", "Month", "Seagrass", "Wwrefuge", "Bathymetry", "Salinity", "Wtemp")],
    type = "response",
    n.trees = 3000
)
```

I have also tried adding a column to the new dataset called Count with NA values but this also returned the same error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with not having a Count variable and is rather an issue with `newManateedata`, where some of the variables differ. It's possible `randomForest()` implicitly converts certain variable types (e.g., characters to factors) and expects you to do the same in the new dataset.

Comment: Hey Noah, I have checked and both datasets have the exact same variables formatted the same way.